# Didn't rerender? Firebase and React-Native login after signup

Tags: firebase, react-native

This error is thrown:

```
there is no user record corresponding to this identifier
```

from this code:

```
    const createAccount = () => {
        if (password === passwordTwo) {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                alert(errorMessage)

            }).then(
                firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then(navigation.navigate('homeDashboard', { userEmail }))

            );
        } else {
            alert('passwords dont match')
        }

    }
```

I know it has something to do with the database not being updated before the "then" is called, I tried doing an await function but couldn't get that to work, If I rerender the home page (where nav is pointing) it is updated with the route info so I know if works it's just not getting rerendered or something? Any good solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your then() methods look off to me. Seems like they are missing an callback.

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

I rewrote your function to the following and tested it.

```
const createAccount = () => {
  if (password === passwordTwo) {
    firebase
     .auth()
     .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
     .catch(function (error) {
       // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        alert(errorMessage);
     })
    .then(() => {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('res.user.uid', res.user.uid);
          // Here you would generally like to do something with the user id
          // maybe put it in the store, so you can use it in your homeDashBoard
          // or in other parts of your application were the user is logged in.
          navigation.navigate('homeDashboard', { userEmail });
        });
     });
    } else {
       alert('passwords dont match');
     }
};
```